# C# LDAP query parent domain

Tags: c#, ldap, subdomain

I'm currently trying to retrieve users from a domain :
corp.mydomain.com
In this domain i'm supposed to have a organization (o=corp.mydomain.com).
But when i'm printing my current context I find :        DC=hq,DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com

So I guess i'm in a child domain of the one I need to reach. So when I'm trying to do a DirectorySearcher, I've got a Referral error. 
I have a username and a password for the "o=corp.mydomain.com" but I just don't get how to use it...

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: Actually I worked it out I don't know how but I really hate AD :)

Comment: Don't worry, we all do xD
Please post your solution as answer for future reference.

Comment: it was just a problem in my code actually, the solution does'nt really answer my question. And actually it was just a stupid thing I did'nt notice in my code so it would'nt help anyone :) thx anyway